# Prove two definitions of $\limsup$ are equivalent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let ($x_n$) be a real sequence. Prove the following:

If both
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\sup_{m\geq n}x_m\Big)$
 and 
$\displaystyle\inf_{n\geq 0}\,\sup_{m\geq n}x_m$
 exist, then 
$\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\Big(\sup_{m\geq n}x_m\Big) = \inf_{n\geq 0}\,\sup_{m\geq n}x_m$

Comment: This follows readily from seeing that $\sup_{m\geqslant n} x_m$ is a monotone decreasing sequence.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Note that the suprema are over smaller and smaller sets, since they are over shrinking tails of the underlying sequence. Do you see that you are therefore dealing with the limit of a monotone sequence?